# Как бот в телеграмме может принимать ответ от юзера и позже использовать его?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, python-3.8

Хотелось бы, что бы бот задавал вопрос "как мне тебя звать?" , а после ответа юзера, он запоминал его ответ и постоянно обращался как это пожелал юзер, пример:
Бот: привет, для начала, как мне тебя звать?
юзер: Михаил
бот: Хорошо, Михаил, рад познакомиться!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у каждого пользователя есть уникальный id, его выдаёт телеграм. У себя на стороне бота заводишь БД. В БД таблицу пользователей с полями: id и name. Когда пользователь впервые обращается (то есть, он ещё в БД не записан), то спрашиваешь, как он хочет называться и сохраняешь. При последующих обращениях вытаскиваешь из БД данные.

Если не хочешь заморачиваться, можешь запоминать в простом dict - глобальной переменной, однако, телеграм бот не редко валится и данные будут теряться. Можешь попроще хранилище взять, чем SQL СУБД, например, в redis, там данные хранятся в виде ключ-значение, но таким образом будет сложно добавлять иные данные.

Comment: Хорошо, попробую, спасибо!